# How to efficiently bind IEnumerable interface on a generic List on Microsoft Fakes

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

Following the instructions found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-shims-to-isolate-your-application-from-other-assemblies-for-unit-testing?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Binding_interfaces), when I try to bind IEnumerable interface to a Shim of a generic list, I'm receiving a NullReferenceException. 
The following simple test reproduces the issue:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Generic.Fakes;
using Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class TestFixture
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestBind()
        {
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                var shimList = new ShimList<int>();
                var actualList = new List<int>() { 1 };
                shimList.Bind((IEnumerable<int>) actualList);
                shimList.Bind((IEnumerable) actualList);
                foreach (var item in shimList.Instance)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(item, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of the test passing, a NullReferenceException is thrown. Any ideas on why this is happenning?

Comment: You are binding an integer list to a string list. That seems incorrect.

Comment: @Silvermind Edited. You were right. However, the outcome is still the same